# Break a string in two based on one of the prefixes in the array

Tags: php

So I have medical licenses that are kept as a string in the db.
 I need a way to show a license letter(s) (prefix) and number separately.

The array of prefixes is pre-defined:

```
$license_letters = array('20A', 'A', 'C', 'CNM', 'G', 'NP', 'PA');
```

And licenses look like 20A345000, C11006, G678999, PA200200, and so on.
So I need to be able to get '20A' and '345000' or 'C' and '11006' for any license.

Searching by the first digit will not work because one of the possible prefixes is 20A.
I'm pretty sure there must be a simple solution, but I can't think of it.
Would appretiate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is true that no license string is a part of any other (you don't have both "A" and "AB" in the list), then just loop through and find the first match as follows:

```
function parts($licenseString) {
    $foreach($license_letters AS $prefix) {
        if(strpos($licenseString, $prefix) === 0) {
            return [$prefix, substr($licenseString, strlen($prefix)];
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I meant to use === in the compare. strpos returns 'false' when no match is found, we want a match at position zero, hence we are looking for a return value which is specifically 0 (type number). Thanks for commenters pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified it slightly, but it definitely put me on the right path.

Comment: 'strpos': should it '=== 0' rather than '== 0'? something to do with false and 0 being similar when testing using 'double equals'?

Comment: Yes, I have actually usedstripos and '===0'

Comment: If you do have both "A" and "AB" in the list, this should still work as long as "AB" is in the list before "A". So the list in the question should be reordered so that "CNM" comes before "C".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to sort the array of prefixes by the length of the string values inside of them to avoid cases with multi-character prefixes (for example '20A') could get confused with single character prefixes (for example 'A'):

```
/**
 * Compare two string values
 *
 * @param $value1 string 1st value to compare
 * @param $value2 string 2nd value to compare
 *
 * @return bool true if the second string is longer than the first
 */
function compareStringLength($value1, $value2)
{
    return (strlen($value1) < strlen($value2));
}

/**
 * Parse a license string
 *
 * @param     $license         string
 * @param     $licensePrefixes array of license prefixes
 *
 * @return array [prefix,license without prefix]
 */
function parseLicense($license, $licensePrefixes)
{
    //The limit to number of times the license prefix will be replaced
    $limit = 1;
    foreach ($licensePrefixes AS $prefix) {
        if (strpos($license, $prefix) !== false) {
            $license = str_replace($prefix, "", $license, $limit);

            return array($prefix, $license);
        }
    }
}

$licensePrefixesArray = array('20A', 'A', 'C', 'CNM', 'G', 'NP', 'PA');

/*
Sort the array to prevent confusion with multi-character prefixes (for example '20A')
and single character prefixes (for example 'A')
*/
usort($licensePrefixesArray, "compareStringLength");

print_r(parseLicense("20A345000", $licensePrefixesArray));
print_r(parseLicense("PA200200", $licensePrefixesArray));
print_r(parseLicense("A2533226", $licensePrefixesArray));
```

Comment: be careful, a prefix is only a prefix if the string STARTS with the prefix, not if the prefix appears later in the string. In other words it is not good enough for strpos(...) !== false, you actually need strpos(...) === 0. (See answer above...). The sorting should be unnecessary as long as no prefix begins with another prefix ("A" and "AB"), and in fact it is beneficial to order the prefix array with the most commonly used ones first to optimize performance...